# How to modify zxing for keeping on scanning?

Tags: android, qr-code

I have developed an application with QR code scanner based on zxing,but i am facing a problem that how to modify the code so that scanner can keep on scan s sequence of qr code to get data until the user stopped it.
  Can anybody give me some advice?

```
public class ScanLibraryCardActivity extends CaptureActivity {
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private String uid, bName, authors, publisher, edition, callNumber,
        location;
private int total;
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
JSONArray user = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // CameraManager
}

@Override
public void handleDecode(final Result obj, Bitmap barcode) {

    uid = obj.getText();
    if (uid.matches("\\d+"))
        new CheckCorrectUser().execute();
    else {
        CustomizedDialog.showResultDialog(ScanLibraryCardActivity.this,
                "Invalid user");
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ScanLibraryCardActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}

class CheckCorrectUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    int success;

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ScanLibraryCardActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(Tag.getTagUid(), uid));
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(Url.getUrl_GetUserData(),
                "GET", params);
        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            success = json.getInt(Tag.getTagSuccess());

            if (success == 1) {

                user = json.getJSONArray("user");
                JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);
                total = c.getInt("total");
            } else {
                // error pop-up
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (success == 1) {
                    CustomizedDialog.showResultDialog(
                            ScanLibraryCardActivity.this, "Valid user");
                } else {
                    // allow user to do any function without save the
                    // data
                    CustomizedDialog.showResultDialog(
                            ScanLibraryCardActivity.this, "Invalid user");
                }

            }

        });
    }
}

}



public class CaptureActivity extends Activity implements Callback {

private CaptureActivityHandler handler;
private ViewfinderView viewfinderView;
private boolean hasSurface;
private Vector<BarcodeFormat> decodeFormats;
private String characterSet;
private InactivityTimer inactivityTimer;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private boolean playBeep;
private static final float BEEP_VOLUME = 0.10f;
private boolean vibrate;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // CameraManager
    CameraManager.init(getApplication());
    viewfinderView = (ViewfinderView) findViewById(R.id.viewfinder_view);
    hasSurface = false;
    inactivityTimer = new InactivityTimer(this);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview_view);
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    if (hasSurface) {
        initCamera(surfaceHolder);
    } else {
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }
    decodeFormats = null;
    characterSet = null;

    playBeep = true;
    AudioManager audioService = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if (audioService.getRingerMode() != AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL) {
        playBeep = false;
    }
    initBeepSound();
    vibrate = true;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (handler != null) {
        handler.quitSynchronously();
        handler = null;
    }
    CameraManager.get().closeDriver();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    inactivityTimer.shutdown();
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void initCamera(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    try {
        CameraManager.get().openDriver(surfaceHolder);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        return;
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        return;
    }
    if (handler == null) {
        handler = new CaptureActivityHandler(this, decodeFormats,
                characterSet);
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (!hasSurface) {
        hasSurface = true;
        initCamera(holder);
    }

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    hasSurface = false;

}

public ViewfinderView getViewfinderView() {
    return viewfinderView;
}

public Handler getHandler() {
    return handler;
}

public void drawViewfinder() {
    viewfinderView.drawViewfinder();

}


public void handleDecode(final Result obj, Bitmap barcode) {
    inactivityTimer.onActivity();
    playBeepSoundAndVibrate();

}

private void initBeepSound() {
    if (playBeep && mediaPlayer == null) {
        // The volume on STREAM_SYSTEM is not adjustable, and users found it
        // too loud,
        // so we now play on the music stream.
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(beepListener);

        AssetFileDescriptor file = getResources().openRawResourceFd(
                R.raw.beep);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(file.getFileDescriptor(),
                    file.getStartOffset(), file.getLength());
            file.close();
            mediaPlayer.setVolume(BEEP_VOLUME, BEEP_VOLUME);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }
}

private static final long VIBRATE_DURATION = 200L;

private void playBeepSoundAndVibrate() {
    if (playBeep && mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
    if (vibrate) {
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(VIBRATE_DURATION);
    }
}

/**
 * When the beep has finished playing, rewind to queue up another one.
 */
private final OnCompletionListener beepListener = new OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
    }
};


}
```

Comment: Since you use zxing library, you can do anything. Zxing scanner is the best one. Have you extend the `captureActivity`? Show your code.

Comment: the relative code has been posted.The situation is when the code is undesired,an error dialog is prompted,then click the ok button and restart scanning qr code

Comment: the above code is fine. What is your question??

Comment: can i do not restart the activity to have the same result?

Comment: I am not getting you.

Comment: I means is it necessary to restart the activity for restarting the scanning process?I have tried restarting the scanning process without restart the activity but it doesn't work

Comment: AFAIK, You should refresh the activity once you get the result. Else it will not scan again.